# SSRS switch and datediff

Tags: reporting-services

I am writing a report that needs to display a different datediff calculation based on a specific Value from a column. If the order is "Active" start time to Now or if the order is ceased start time to stop time.

The individual DateDiff expressions work but when I try to combine them in one expression using either switch or IIF I get errors.

Any suggestions would be great.

```
=IIF(Fields!OrderStatus.Value="Active", DateDiff("d",Fields!OrderStartTime.Value, "Now"()),
       IIF(Fields!OrderStatus.Value="Discontinued", DateDiff("d",Fields!OrderStartTime.Value, Fields!DiscontinueTime.Value)
       )
)


=Switch(Fields!OrderStatus.Value="Active", 
DateDiff("d",Fields!OrderStartTime.Value, "Now"()),
Fields!OrderStatus.Value="Discontinued", 
DateDiff("d",Fields!OrderStartTime.Value, Fields!DiscontinueTime.Value),
)
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the third argument for your second iif statement (in this case, it'll be {Nothing}.  This should work:

=IIF(Fields!OrderStatus.Value="Active",DateDiff("d",Fields!OrderStartTime.Value,Today()),IIF(Fields!OrderStatus.Value="Discontinued",DateDiff("d",Fields!OrderStartTime.Value,Fields!DiscontinuedTime.Value),Nothing))

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. I suspected it was probably something basic